# Error TS1005: ';' expected. TypeScript Angular 6 For First Build error rxjs inside node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building my first Angular Application. I'm creating a new Angular application using this command `ng new purchase-section`. But when I executing the application using `ng serve -o` I got the following error.

> ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005:
>   ';' expected. node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error
>   TS1005: ';' expected. node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77):
>   error TS1109: Expression expected.

I have inspected `types.d.ts` as I know it is created by Angular.
I'm not able to understand the error. Note that after I got this error I deleted `node_modules` and I installed using `npm install` wished I got away still I got this error.

Here is my `package.JSON` file:

```
{
 "name": "purchase-section",
 "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
 "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
     "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
     "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
     "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
     "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
       "core-js": "^2.5.4",
       "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
       },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
         "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
         "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
          "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
           "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
           "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
            "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
             "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
              "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
               "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
                "karma": "^4.0.0",
                 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
                  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
                   "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
                 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
                 "protractor": "^5.4.2",
                  "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
                  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
                "typescript": "~2.7.2"
                 }
               }
```

Comment: Related issue on RxJS GitHub page: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4512

Comment: Hey did you ever find a answer to this problem, I am having the same issue and none of the below answers solved anything. By the way I am using ng4(Angular 4).

Comment: which line is line 81?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941420/4378475

Answer (score 80):

I had the same issue. I investigated that [rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/releases) released a new version: `6.4.0`. And it broke the build. According to [review](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4405#pullrequestreview-196802187), the minimum supported version of TypeScript is `2.8`. If you don't want to update TypeScript version, just change `"rxjs": "^6.0.0", to "rxjs": "6.3.3"` in `package.json`.

Comment: i have same issue my "typescript": "~3.2.2" and "rxjs": "6.3.3" please tell me anyone how to solve this error?

Comment: just change "rxjs": "^6.0.0", to "rxjs": "6.3.3" in package.json and run command npm install again so it will update it in your project. Now It will work

Comment: Also if your package.json has a dependency for rxjs-compat then make that also 6.3.3 so you will not get any errors

Comment: @kalai hi , i had the same problem , i changed rxjs version to 6.3.3 , and removed node modules and installed again , and now it is working , i am using typescript version 2.7.2

Comment: @codemt my project running successfully on command prompt but getting error only in visual studio 2017

Comment: @kalai then it looks some problem with VS  version , upgrade to the latest version and see what happens.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this does not help me to fix the problem. Any ideas? I am trying to run the command `npm start` for the following project https://github.com/angulardeveloper-io/ngrx-store-app.

Answer (score 41):

I was facing the same issue while developing an angular6 project. I spent more time finally it's working for me.

Here is the solution:

1. Open "package.json"
2. `rxjs` and "TypeScript" verstion like below screenshot

   [image]
3. Change like the below screenshot:

   [image]
4. Next go to your project folder and delete "node_modules" folder.
5. After delete, next run `npm install` in your project folder
6. Finally run `ng serve`. It should work (I tried 3 projects and confirmed).

Comment: This seems to work for me but do you know what the actual reason for this error is ? I mean until now it worked fine with the "^" symbol. Do you maybe have more details regarding what is causing this error ? Thanks

Comment: for details read @langrenn answer in below I think it is the reason.

Answer (score 33):

Just remove `^` character from `"rxjs": "^6.0.0"` from `package.json` file and make it `"rxjs": "6.0.0"`. It should work fine.

Comment: I then had to delete my `node_modules` and run `npm i` again, but it worked. (Alternative : `npm update`)

Answer (score 13):

Today I faced the same issue. None of the above answers worked except a comment from one @Nasreen Ustad. So what you have to do is:

1. Go to package.json and modify `"rxjs": "^6.0.0"` to `"rxjs": "6.0.0"`
2. Run `npm update` in your project

No need to change typescript version.(Mine: `"typescript": "~2.7.2"`)

Comment: @shubham actually I have now moved to angular 10. Couldn't simulate this.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the project directory run: `npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save`

Answer (score 4):

In your `Package.json` file remove `^` symbol (caret) from `"rxjs": "^6.0.0"` and add `"rxjs": "6.0.0"` it will work fine.

Comment: This is just a duplicate answer of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54436825/) IMO. Before posting here, check the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the TypeScript dependency version to `^2.8`

Answer (score 2):

Your package.json has following lines:

```
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",

"typescript": "~2.7.2"
```

This tells npm to install the following versions

rxjs: Latest version in version 6 series which is [6.4.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs)

typescript: Latest patched version in minor version 2.7 which is [2.7.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript)

Now RxJS module also installs the type definition files for TypeScript. The type definition file included in the rxjs module that got installed in your project is not compatible with typescript version installed in the same project.

So as a solution in your package.json file you can either bump up the version of Typescript to say 2.8 as

`"typescript": "^2.8.0"`

or bump down the version of ngrx to something like

`"ngrx": "~6.0.0"` and

do a fresh npm install.

You can check the version number of the module installed by looking in following files:

```
node_modules/rxjs/package.json and
node_modules/typescript/package.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Update in package.json
rxjs": "6.3.3"

in terminal
1. run npm update
2. run ng serve

It should compile successfully

Answer (score 2):

Check your typescript version with below command.

`~ tsc --version
   Version 3.3.3`

As this is the latest typescript version, I've upgraded the project angular version to 7 by running below command in project home folder. It solved the issue.

~]# `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the version for rxjs and typescript. My `package.json` has the following entries:

```
"typescript": "^2.7.2"
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
```

I also had to upgrade angular cli.

Answer (score 1):

My current project is in asp.net MVC with angular 8. After updating the angular project from 8 to 9, the angular build working fine but facing the above problem for MVC build. (on azure)

Just hiding the

> node_modules

folder, solved my problem.

[image: hide node_modules folder]

Comment: yes thanks - visual studio excludes node_modules when it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Angular and/or rxjs version is not compatible with TypeScript.

Remove the `~` sign in the TypeScript version, add `^` instead. Then, install packages again.

Try running `npm start` and `ng build` prior to `ng serve`.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio after this. What is your TS version now?

Comment: this helped me. Thanks! (new version 2.9.2 worked perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

These two changes what you want:

```
// in package.json:
```

`"rxjs": "^6.2.2"` ==> `"rxjs": "latest"`
`"typescript": "2.7.2"` ==> `"typescript": "2.8"`

where `==>` means to replace

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the other answers. But I found issue. I had ts lint plugin installed which forced file to be ended without space. I removed it and it is working.

You can also remove the space going to that specific file.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `npm` version to the latest, if it isn't, with:

```
npm update -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall and reinstall angular CLI.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this error with:
rxjs/store: ^6.4.0
typescript: ~2.7.2
angular/cli ~6.0.0

Updated everything to the latest except rxjs
rxjs/store: ^6.3.3
typescript: ~3.1.1
angular/cli ~7.0.3

Basically I created an blank new project (ng new newProject) and installed @ngrx/store which brought down v6.3.3.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project directory run:

```
npm install -s rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 0):

The below steps resolved my issue

There are two files that have to modify.

- node_modules\@ag-grid-community\core\dist\cjs\utils\index.js

> //export * from "./utils";

- node_modules\@ag-grid-community\core\dist\cjs\utils\index.d.ts

> //_export(require("./utils"));

comment utils as above. now npm start

Answer (score 0):

So there are many ways to fix this and some methods work for some and some not.

Here is the basic thing you can do.

Try removing node_modules. You can remove manually that from your project or you can use this command rm -rf node_modules. If it shows permission issue then use sudo rm -rf node_modules.

Then

Go to your package.json file in your angular project.

Check for typeScript version .
If its "typescript": "^ 2.9.2", simply remove ^ and make it "typescript": " 2.9.2"

And also check the same for rxjs . If it's  "rxjs": "^6.3.3", change it to  "rxjs": "6.3.3".

Then do npm install once.

Then you can run the command which you were using like npm run build to build packages or npm start/ng build etc.

If this will not work try upgrading your typescript version to 2.8 or higher as it seems that rxjs version 6 above needs typescript version 2.8 or higher.

If the above 2 will not work add the below in your package.json file.

"@types/react": "17.0.2",

And remove ^ from the version of most of the packages.
I hope any one of the above will resolve your problem.