# Attempted to use @angular/material and now my project has a (versioning?) error

Tags: angular

I think I am having a versioning issue with my Angular project.  I would ideally like to be operating on Angular 6.  I have tried to follow many guides on how to reversion everything but cant seem to get it working.

here is my ng version

```
$ ng version

Angular CLI: 6.1.0
Node: 10.16.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.2
... core

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.12.4
@angular-devkit/core                7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics          0.7.0 (cli-only)
@angular/animations                 6.1.10
@angular/cdk                        8.1.3
@angular/common                     6.1.10
@angular/compiler                   6.1.10
@angular/compiler-cli               6.1.10
@angular/forms                      6.1.10
@angular/http                       6.1.10
@angular/language-service           6.0.5
@angular/material                   8.1.3
@angular/platform-browser           6.1.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   6.1.10
@angular/platform-server            6.1.10
@angular/router                     6.1.10
@ngtools/webpack                    7.2.4
@schematics/angular                 0.7.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                  0.7.0 (cli-only)
rxjs                                6.5.2
typescript                          2.7.2
webpack                             4.28.4
```

node -v = v10.16.2
npm -v = 6.9.0

This whole issue started when I tried to add some @angular/material components to my existing and working project.  The current compile error I get is:

$ ng serve -o
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

```
Date: 2019-08-16T17:29:00.175Z
Hash: 82494200f97101bdd802
Time: 3853ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.93 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 92.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 139 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.css, styles.css.map (styles) 153 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 327 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,92): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

I could start a new project and port my code over if that is easier?

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Project:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.10",
    "@mapbox/leaflet-omnivore": "^0.3.4",
    "@mapbox/togeojson": "^0.16.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "6.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "d3": "^5.9.7",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is a material and cdk version 6.1.0, try using that. Your @angular/core version should be 6.1.10, too.

Comment: I would suggest to clean up the node_modules, the node cache and reinstall the dependencies.Also your best bet would be to downgrade material to `6.4.6` and update angular core to v6 too

Comment: Still getting errors on material and cdk 6.1.0 and core 6.1.10
what exactly would i clean in the node_modules?

Comment: delete your node_modules and run `npm cache clean --force`. and then go ahead and install dependencies again. You ca do `npm i @angular/material@6 @angular/cdk@6` for installing v6

Answer (score 0):

Previously solved in this thread: [Error TS1005: ';' expected. TypeScript Angular 6 For First Build error rxjs inside node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434333/error-ts1005-expected-typescript-angular-6-for-first-build-error-rxjs-insi)

Per that thread, the two solution options look like:

1. Reduce your rxjs version to lower than 6.4.0 - example "rxjs": "6.3.3".

OR

2. Update your TypeScript version to 2.8 or higher.

Comment: The tilde `~` matches the most recent patch version (the third number) for the specified minor version (the second number).
~1.2.3 will match all 1.2.x versions but will hold off on 1.3.0.

The caret `^` is more relaxed. It matches the most recent minor version (the second number) for the specified major version (the first number).
^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but **will hold off on 2.0.0.**

Comment: Yes, I understand. Looks like there were some TypeScript versioning errors with rxjs v6.4.0 where it required at least TypeScript v2.8. So perhaps a more accurate answer is to reduce rxjs version. Will edit my answer to be more accurate/descriptive, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. delete your node_modules
2. run `npm cache clean --force`
3. Install v6 version of dependencies either by updating version in package.jsion or by running `npm i @angular/material@6 @angular/cdk@6 --save`

I would suggest to use material **v6.4.6** which is compatible with angular v6 and Typescript v2.7.x.